# Foreign key column not shown in vs Dataset DataTable

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sqldataadapter

I created a procedure with primary key constraint. Itis working fine. Now I'll try to add this procedure in vs dataset through Dataset-->TableAdapter-->use existing stored procedure -->finished. It does not show the foreign key column. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Add some code so that we can work on something!!

Comment: have you used fill method for data adapter?

Comment: I am new for dot net. can you explain once.

Comment: @user3085540 Can you check my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you use **fill** method for datasource it doesnot add schema information to the DataSet.
From [Adding Existing Constraints to a DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49z48hxc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
To populate a DataSet with existing primary key constraint information from 
a data source, you can either call the FillSchema method of the DataAdapter,
or set the MissingSchemaAction property of the DataAdapter to AddWithKey 
before calling Fill.
```

how to add schema information to a DataSet using **FillSchema**.

```
DataSet custDataSet = new DataSet();

custAdapter.FillSchema(custDataSet, SchemaType.Source, "Customers");
custAdapter.Fill(custDataSet, "Customers");
```

how to add schema information to a DataSet using the **MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey** property of the Fill method.

```
DataSet custDataSet = new DataSet();

custAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
custAdapter.Fill(custDataSet, "Customers");
```